# fetching data from MySQL database, works on localhost, but fails on linux server

Tags: php, apache, select, mysqli, prepared-statement

I am trying to fetch some rows from MySQL server through PHP, which works perfectly on localhost, but fails when I try to run it on my own Linux server (ubuntu 14.04).

What i am trying to do, is fetching a list of users from the "users" table in my database. I call the method like this:

```
$members = $this->con->getAllMembers();
```

my getAllMembers() looks like this:

```
function getAllMembers(){
        $stmt = $this->con->prepare("SELECT users.username, profileinfo.joindate FROM users 
                                    LEFT JOIN profileinfo ON users.user_id = profileinfo.userID");
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($username, $joindate);

        $members = array ();
        while($stmt->fetch()){
            $user = new User();
            $user->username = $username;
            $user->joindate = $joindate;
            array_push($members, $user);
        }
        $stmt->close();

        return $members;
    }
```

And then I try to echo out a list like this (shortened down):

```
foreach($members as $member){
        $joindate = date('j. M-o',$member->joindate);
        echo "  <tr>
                    <td><a href='".MAINPATH."profile/".$member->username."'>$member->username</a></td>
                    <td>$joindate</td>
                </tr>";
    }
```

The weird thing is that it works like it should on my localhost (Windows machine running apache server through XAMPP)
But when I run it on the Linux server, it stops completely after the getAllMembers() method is called. I can't even echo out a single value after it is called. I can fetch single values, insert and update on the Linux server, but the above just doesn't work for some reason.

I really hope someone can help me out here.

The Linux server runs: PHP Version 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.4
And my local apache server runs PHP Version 5.5.15, if that is relevant at all.

Comment: I don't see any handling. Check for sql errors reported by mysql.

Comment: So turn on error_reporting/display_errors, start checking for sql failures, put in debug echo statements to see how far things get before puking, blah blah blah. e.g. start doing basic debugging.

Comment: linux is case sensitive so some times it happens that when we import tables from windows machine the fields name get in to lower case and query return nothing, try profileinfo.userID as profileinfo.userid or check the field names, not sure but it happens with me.

Comment: So sorry I've wasted your time :/ I got the error: unkown class: User.. which means that I didn't find the User class php file. i found out that i did include it, but forgot to upload my index file, which includes all my neccesary files..